# Firebase observe data async

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to observe data from the Realtime Database in an asynchronous way.

For this I use "withCheckedContinuation" to return the result but I have seen in the IOS documentation that Continuation can only be "resume" once so every time I update the data in the database this breaks my app.

I would like to know if what I am trying is possible or if there is some other way to deal with this problem so that the function remains asynchronous.

```
class StoreFirebase {
    private let ref = Database.database().reference()
    var driverObserver: UInt?
    var driverReference: DatabaseReference?
    
    func getDriverSingleLocation(_ uuid: String) async -> Result<StoreData, Error> {
        
        return await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            driverReference?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? StoreData {
                    continuation.resume(returning: .success(dictionary))
                } else {
                    continuation.resume(returning: .failure(HTTPError(.badRequest)))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getDriverLocation(_ uuid: String) async -> Result<StoreData, Error> {
        driverReference = ref.child("driversAvailable").child(uuid)
        
        return await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            var nillableContinuation: CheckedContinuation<Result<StoreData, Error>, Never>? = continuation

            driverObserver = driverReference?.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? StoreData {
                    nillableContinuation?.resume(returning: .success(dictionary))
                    
                    
                } else {
                    nillableContinuation?.resume(returning: .failure(HTTPError(.badRequest)))
                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into AsyncStream

Answer (score 2):

Thx for the comment, fixed it with AsyncStream

```
class RealTimeDatabaseService: RealTimeDatabaseProtocol {
    private let ref = Database.database().reference()
    var driverObserver: UInt?
    var driverReference: DatabaseReference?
    
    func getDriverLocation(_ uuid: String) -> AsyncStream <Result<StoreData, Error>> {
        driverReference = ref.child("driversAvailable").child(uuid)
        
        return AsyncStream { continuation in
            driverObserver = driverReference?.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? StoreData {
                    continuation.yield(.success(dictionary))
                } else {
                    continuation.yield(.failure(HTTPError(.badRequest)))
                    continuation.finish()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func getDriverLocationResult() async  {
        for try await response in 'getDriverLocation'("uid") {
            switch response {
            case .success(let storeDate):
                print("completed: \(storeDate)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```